# How to fix $yy’’=y’\implies y=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^{k+r}, (k+r+1)a_{k+1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{k-r}(n+r+1)(n+r+2)a_{k-n-r}a_{n+2} $ if false?

Tags: solution-verification, recurrence-relations, inverse-function, nonlinear-analysis, frobenius-method

The goal is a recurrence relation for the series coefficients; maybe the

> [Quantile Mechanics](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucahwts/lgsnotes/EJAM_Quantiles.pdf) [$(93)$ to $(97)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCu4B.jpg)

method, like the [Frobenius method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method), to solve $yy’’=y’$. First, substitute $y=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^{k+r}$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty(n+r+1)(n+r+2)a_ma_{n+2}x^{n+r}x^{m+r}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+r+1)a_{k+1}x^{k+r}$$

Equating coefficients with [Kronecker $\delta_{u,v}$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerDelta.html):

$$(k+r+1)a_{k+1}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty(n+r+1)(n+r+2)a_ma_{n+2}\delta_{k+r,m+n+2r}$$ and make $n$’s upper bound finite since the double sum is $0$ when $k+r\ne m+n+2r\iff k\ne m+n+r$. Following Quantile Mechanics, erase $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty$, $m=k-n-r$, and the upper bound of $n$ being $k-r$ is just a guess:

$$\boxed{(k+r+1)a_{k+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{k-r}(n+r+1)(n+r+2)a_{k-n-r}a_{n+2}}$$

Is this recurrence relation true and if not, what is the recurrence relation for the series coefficients of $yy’’=y’$?

Comment: Since this is an [autonomous differential equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Autonomous.html), we can use the substitution $v=y'$ to obtain $v'(y)=1/y\implies z=y'=\log y(x)+C$. That may point to why the method of Frobenius fares poorly here. On the other hand, one may have more success by working with $y$ as the independent variable by writing the ODE as $x'(y)=1/(C+\log y)$ instead. (Though in that case one should probably not expand around $y=0$.)

Comment: @Semiclassical An example of the Frobenius-related method is [pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCu4B.jpg). If one tried the same on $y’=\ln(y)+C$, it may not work. Are you sure this one does not work on $yy’’=y’$?

Comment: The ODE used in that case is $w''(v)=w (w')^2$, in which case the substitution $z=w'(v)$ yields $w''(v)=dz/dv=z'(w) v'(z)=w z'(w)$ and thus $z'(w)=z^2$. This solves to $z(w)=w'=-1/(w+A)$. This is still a bit ugly, but it doesn't yield the same log issues that the other ODE does. (In particular, writing the ODE as $v'(w)=-w-A$ yields $v=-w^2/2-Aw-B$. Hence $v$ is polynomial in $w$ and series reversion to recover $v$ will likely succeed.) So while a Frobenius solution may work in that case of a nonlinear equation, it doesn't guarantee it will work in others.

Comment: Taking into account that, you need to inverse $$x=e^{c_1} \text{Ei}(\log (y)-c_1)+c_2$$ very little hope (in my opinion)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, but the [inverse error function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseErf/06/01/02/0004/) has a fairly simple recurrence relation series, so maybe $yy’’=y’$ can at least be tried.